# False Positive option don't appear on projects

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using Sonarqube on Ubuntu 12.01 machine. I use Sonar Runner with Jenkins plugin to analyse my code.

The problem came when I execute an analysis for new projects. For example I have saved on Sonar A and B project, if I execute analysis for new C project for this project false positive option don't appear.
This occurs since I update Sonar to the last version 4.1.2. With projects that have been created with the previous version all works fine.
Anyone knows what is the problem?
For my company the possibility of mark errors like false positive is really important.

Answer (score 26):

The "False positive" action is only available with the "Administer Issues" permission, so you might want to check the permissions on the newly created project(s). If it is indeed an issue with permissions, then your next step will probably to modify the default permission template associated with projects, so that you get the right permissions upon creation.