# Sonarqube 5 - how do I mark false-positive?

Tags: sonarqube

I've recently installed SonarQube 5.0.1, but I can't find where to mark issues as false-positive.  In the drop-down box where this option used to be, the only option is "Link to JIRA", and I'm signed in as admin.

Is this feature now provided as part of an optional plugin?

EDIT:  I have added a screenshot of exactly what I see in the UI.

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have found the answer here: [False Positive option don't appear on projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374336/false-positive-option-dont-appear-on-projects)

The issue is that although the admin LDAP group I belong to was granted "Administer System" rights in Global Permissions, it also needs to be added excplicitly to Project Permissions (either per project, or to the default template).

Comment: Note that the minimal permission required is _Administer Issues_ as per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870516) below.

Answer (score 25):

In SonarQube Version 5.5:

If you have given "Administer Issues" permission to the project.

[image]

Then you will see this option on click of Open.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In 5.0, the "False Positive" action is not in a dropdown:

[image]

Comment: I don't have the link there either in 5.0.1