# How to suppress sonarqube rule in a particular case?

Tags: python, pyqt, sonarqube, pyqt4

I want to suppress the "Method names should comply with a naming convention" rule in my python code, but only in the case when I'm overriding a method from a Qt class.

For example: inheriting from `QWidget` and overriding the `resizeEvent()` method (which is not compliant with the rule).

According to the [FAQ](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Howtoremovefalsepositiveissues) there are `//NOSONAR` and `@SuppressWarnings` (which will fit my needs) but these are only available for java.

Is there some special keyword for this or should I do something like creating new custom rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark the issue as a false positive through the SonarQube UI, as shown in this related question: [Sonarqube 5 - how do I mark false-positive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646256/sonarqube-5-how-do-i-mark-false-positive)

I've created the following ticket to the SonarQube Python Plugin's backlog to consider adding the `NOSONAR` comment marker support in an upcoming version: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPY-129

Comment: I know about it and we use it as a workaround. But NOSONAR would be great, thanks!

Comment: Can I have a link for that ticket?

Comment: Sorry I meant to include it originally - now fixed